# Question regarding driving an audio system with a generator (without inverter)

Tags: power-supply, audio, inverter, generator

We're arranging a music event where we're going to drive a few speakers and a dj controller. We've been trying to find a generator that would work and so far we only have access to three. All three generators are of the classic kind, they do not have inverters. The output is connected directly to the alternator.

The most likely candidate right now is a Honda ECMT 7000. It has an RMS of 6500 in triplephase which is more than enough for us.

Our issue is interference and voltage spikes. We're afraid that the generator could spike and break our equipment that will be connected through a power central 220v that converts triplephase to singlephase.

I've tried to search the web for an answer and everybody says different things. Half of the posts I see say it's fine and they've been doing it for years while the second half says it'll definitely fry the electronics.

What do you guys think? More specs on the generators and audio can be sent on request. The power is not an issue, we already know that. We're worried about the spikes.

Would the fuses in the central and some standard EU socket voltage protectors be fine?

Comment: Can you link specs for the "power central 220v that converts triplephase to singlephase" device?

Comment: @GlennW9IQ Probably something similar to this one: http://images.biltema.com/PAXToImageService.svc/article/xlarge/44727. Although it "converts" 220 V three phase line-neutral voltage to single phase 220 V line-neutral voltage.

Comment: This "spike will kill your equipment" is nonsense. I've done so many concerts and forest parties I've lost count. What you should be concerned about in that very situation is if you have a ridiculously long three phase cable and strong single phase load, like incandescent lights on one phase and the two other being light or unloaded. Then the voltage drop on your neutral will _increase_ the line-neutral voltage on your two other phases. "More light on the stage please!" Meter showing 280 V on the outboard already "No, we'll burn the FOH mixer!" Only 0.1 % of the population understood why.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for technical info, not just a picture of the converter. That doesn't look like a converter - more like a breakout panel.

Comment: @Glenn It is a breakout panel. The beauty of three phase with neutral.

Comment: I understand three phase quite clearly but the OP used terminology that if untested could lead to wrong answers.

Comment: Yeah it might shine through quite clearly that I am not that well studied when it comes to electronics in my post.

@winny
You guys are correct, I do mean a distribution board similar to the one you are talking about, not a converter. My bad.

If we balance the load on all three phases equally, would an inductive generator work for our purposes? I've seen so many split opinions when it comes to inductive generators and audio that I'm unsure what to believe.

Comment: No worries on my side mate, I got you the first time. Yes it will. Just think about what equal load means on a concert. Suppose L1 is your 2 kW power amplifiers, L2 is 2 kW of lights and L3 is your 2 kW smoke machine. L1 goes from 100 W to 4 kW with each bass beat or 4 kW continuous until your fuse blows in case of Enya/dubstep. L2 varies greatly with your light level and L3 is pretty much ON-OFF with the thermostat of your smoke machine. If the cable isn't ridiculously long, you are still fine. I just raise my concerns that you sometimes do end up with 100 meters of cable and unbalanced load.

Comment: @winny We're planning on running a top and a bass on one phase and the other channels top + bass on a second phase. Third phase would be for some very small lights that don't draw pretty much anything. I'm guessing the lights on the third phase could be an issue considering they barely draw any power in this case? We could just skip out on the lights entirely if needed. Cable length would probably be maybe 20m max.

Comment: 20 meters is no problem at all. Go for it!

Comment: @winny Just to clarify, to make sure I don't misunderstand anything, the fact that the generator does not have an inverter or AVR shouldn't be much of an issue with correct load? You've run parties with classic oldschool inductive generators like these before? Without equipment damage? Of course this post is not my only point of data but I'm trying to get clear opinions on it from many sources to make sure I don't do anything stupid.

Comment: No AVR? That's mighty uncommon. Are you sure? Apart from that, save for very big and sudden load drops, I've ran all our audio, light, smoke and whatnot on various gensets (all with AVR), inverter gensets, pure inverters, both sine and modified square wave. Numerous parties and concerts. You need to dig up pure garbage, sub 90s Behringer, to start destroying things. Side note, I did use to work for Lab.gruppen, desining PFC frontends and isolation converters and your average pro audio gear will say 100-240 Vac on the nameplate but have wider margins than consumer products.

Comment: @winny The regulator is stated as being a compound transformer and I'm not sure what that is exactly. The compound transformer part is not listed on Hondas official website, only on a third party supplier.

The product sheet for the Honda have a series of other generators next to it in the sheet. Two have the word AVR as category, two have the word capacitor and two (including the one I have available) have the word inductive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62062/discussion-between-winny-and-arebokert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The times when a conventional generator output voltage or frequency could become unstable is during startup, shutdown, and when it is running out of fuel and starving. Always unplug during these conditions. A well maintained generator will otherwise be a reliable energy source for your electronics.

To keep the voltage in spec, always try to balance the loads between the three phases. If you get them substantially unbalanced, the advantage of the three phases sharing a common wire is lost - particularly with a longer three phase cable.  This can result in one or more phases having an improper voltage.

Comment: So you don't believe there will be much if any issues with a conventional generator if we keep the load on all phases steady and don't put too much load on the generator?

Comment: Just follow the tips in my answer and you should be good. Surge suppressors can give you some added assurance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but should clarify your terminology:

> We're afraid that the generator could spike and break our equipment that will be connected through a power central 220v that converts triplephase to singlephase.

The box doesn't convert anything. It just makes one phase available on each of the blue sockets simply by wiring.

[image]

*Figure 1. Three-phase breakout box.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhvTYp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Breakout box internal wiring. (CircuitLab seems to be struggling with the wire crossings. Connections are marked with dots.)*

The breakout box has no active components inside. It just takes 3-phase L1, L2, L3 and N (and Earth) input - note the pins rather than sockets - and "breaks them out" into two more 3-phase sockets (red) and four (two shown) single-phase sockets (blue). I have not shown the circuit breakers on the schematic.

Comment: That does explain everything a bit further. I was not aware that the distribution board was just a "splitting" of the three phases, I thought there were some conversion going on.